# Access a controller's instance variable from a block using instance_eval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, block

I'm making a breadcrumb module for my Ruby on Rails application, but I wanted a specific syntax - which I thought was good looking and more intuitive for Rails developers.

Here's the deal:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  breadcrumb_for :index, :text => 'Home', :href => -> { root_path }

  def index
  end
end
```

See, it's neat.

You can safely ignore the everything else but that `proc` - what I assign to the `:href` key.

I use `instance_eval` so that when the proc is evaluated it has access to the `root_path` helper.

And it worked. The example above is okay. BUT then I wanted to use an **instance variable** and that didn't work.

Like this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  breadcrumb_for :index, :text => 'Home', :href => -> { @path }

  def index
    @path = root_path
  end
end
```

Now, in that proc context `@path` is `nil`.

What should I do so I can access the instance variables from the block ?

Below is all the code of my module. Note that when I "process" the blocks and use `instance_eval` (aka call my module's `#breadcrumb`) the action should already be evaluated so the instance variable `@path` should already exist.

```
module Breadcrumb
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    cattr_accessor(:_breadcrumb) { [] }

    helper_method :breadcrumb

    def self.breadcrumb_for(*args)
      options = args.pop
      _breadcrumb.push([args, options])
    end
  end

  def breadcrumb
    @breadcrumb ||= self._breadcrumb.map do |item|
      puts item

      if item[0].include?(params[:action]) || item[0][0] == '*'

        text, href = item[1].values_at(:text, :href)

        if text.respond_to?(:call)
          text = instance_eval(&text)
        end

        if href.respond_to?(:call)
          href = instance_eval(&href)
        end

        [text, href]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I just found out that the issue has something to do with the order of the evaluation - if I call `breadcrumb` in the view the instance variable comes `nil` but if I call it inside the controller's actions then the instance variable works.

Answer (score 0):

Oh no. I'm ashamed to say but it was my mistake. The code above works just fine, I was using different variable names in my application, not shown in the excerpt I used in the question.

Thanks anyway, I'll left it here for reference.